# Xamarin IOS SIGSEGV when debugging

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin, segmentation-fault

I am getting an error when I am debugging and mouse over a variable to gets its value, I am then getting this error popup http://gyazo.com/1a3cfe39d135e5807d41d2acf3b54b90
and then the debugger crashes with a SIGSEGV error.

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
2015-03-04 14:31:00.568 AppName[839:11564] critical: Stacktrace:

2015-03-04 14:31:00.568 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2015-03-04 14:31:00.568 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at Core.DataLayer.DataConnection.GetDatabasePath () [0x00063] in /Users/me/Projects/AppName/Core/DataLayer/DataAccess.cs:24
2015-03-04 14:31:00.568 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at Core.DataLayer.DataConnection.SetupDatabaseIfNeeded () [0x00002] in /Users/me/Projects/AppName/Core/DataLayer/DataAccess.cs:88
2015-03-04 14:31:00.569 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at IOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication,Foundation.NSDictionary) [0x0000b] in /Users/me/Projects/AppName/IOS/AppDelegate.cs:66
2015-03-04 14:31:00.569 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool__this___object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00066, 0xffffffff>
2015-03-04 14:31:00.569 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2015-03-04 14:31:00.569 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x000a6, 0xffffffff>
2015-03-04 14:31:00.570 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
2015-03-04 14:31:00.570 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46
2015-03-04 14:31:00.570 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at IOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00008] in /Users/me/Projects/AppName/IOS/Main.cs:17
2015-03-04 14:31:00.570 AppName[839:11564] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>
2015-03-04 14:31:00.570 AppName[839:11564] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2015-03-04 14:31:00.571 AppName[839:11564] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================


Application Terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error. There were variables in Watch window from other project. Clearing all variables helped.